# Are there specialities within the embedded fields

Tags: c++, c, embedded

I've started learning embedded and its 2 main languages (c and c++). But I'm starting to realize that despite the simple learning requirements, embedded is a whole world in and of itself. And once you deal with real projects, you start to realize that you need to learn more "stuff" specific to the hardware used in the device you're working on. This is an issue that rarely came up with the software-only projects I currently work on.

Is it possible to fragment this field into sub-fields? I'm thinking that those with experience in the field may have noticed that some types of projects are different from other types, which has led them to maybe maybe come up with their own categories. For example, when you run into a project, you may think to yourself that it's "outside your field"? Does that happen to you? and if so, what would you call your sub-field or what other sub-fields have you encountered?

Comment: I could add to the answers already given, but I would not add much to that already said.  To get a broad overview of the extent of embedded systems do take a look at http://embedded.com/

Comment: The #1 thing most desktop developers entering into embedded work seem to lack is familiarity with bare-metal hardware programming, board bring up, device drivers, interrupt service routines, rudimentary digital electronics skills enough to understand the "programmer's guide" that is produced for your CPU/MCU, etc.

Comment: Get a real board, like a Rabbit 2000 developer kit, and when you have real hardware, then you're learning real embedded stuff. Otherwise, it's all theory.  :-) Get your hands wet. Not literally. That would be bad for your embedded system boards.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here are a few sub-specialities I can think of:

Assembly Language Specialist

- Yep.  You need to know C and C++.  But some people also specialize in assembly.  These are the experts that are called up to port a RTOS to a new chip, or to squeeze every drop of performance from a highly constrained embedded system (usually to save $$ per unit).
  This person probably is not needed that much these days... but.. yet still critical from time to time.

Device Driver Specialist

- comfortable living between a real OS or RTOS and a piece of hardware.  This person is usually comfortable with lab tools like o-scopes or logic analyzers, thinking in "hex", and understanding the critical nature of timing with HW.   This person reads device data sheets for fun at night, and gets excited about creating the perfect porting driver for some new device.

DSP Specialist

- Digital Signal Processing seems to be its own sub-specialty of embedded, although perhaps a software engineer may not know the exact algorithm details, and may only be implementing what a system or electrical engineer requires.  However, understanding sampling rate theory, FFTs, and some foundational elements from "DSP" is handy and maybe required.  And you still generally must be very aware of timing and your target hardware's restrictions ( sampling rate, noise, bits per sample, etc).

Control Theory Specialist

- Perhaps the same issue as with DSP:  a system or electrical engineer may provide the detailed specs.  But, then again, familiarity with various motors, sensors, and other controllers handled by a microcontroller, would be great.  Throw in a Bode plot, some Laplace transforms or two and some higher math skills... that couldn't hurt too much!

Networking Specialist

- basically the same as the PC world "networking".  Many embedded devices are adding networking connectivity features these days.   TCP/IP sockets, http, etc good to know and understand how to use in a resource constrained device.  Throw in USB and Bluetooth for good measure.

UI Specialist

- more and more embedded devices include 2D graphics, and now more include 3D graphics thanks to the influence of iPhones, etc.  Even though these are still "fat" systems by other embedded device standards, they are still limited.  Just read a bit in the Android Development Guide, and you will realize that you still must consider responsiveness, performance, etc, even in a high end cell phone.
  http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/design/performance.html

And then, of course, every industry is a specialization unto itself.  Consumer Electronics, Military, Avionics, Robotics, Industrial Machines, Medical Devices, etc...

Have fun and good luck!

Answer (score 6):

Yes, there certainly are several sub-fields.  I don't think I can list them all from the top of my head, but the way I see it, there are at least 3 big sub-divisions, and from there, they are further sub-divided.  There are micro-controllers, micro-processors and sand-boxed/VMs.  For example, using a 16bit micro-controller in a drive-by-wire would be an example of the first, a set-top-box like TiVo would be and example of the second, and iPhones and Androids are the latter.

Micro-controllers are very limited, and usually can't even be programmed in C++.  Most of them either has no OS running, or, the most expensive ones, have an RTOS.  Set-top-boxes and any ARM/MIPS/SuperH4/Broadcom chips are much more like a PC, in that they have a linux distribution running in them and you can find most of the same facilities as a PC, and if you can't find one, cross-compiling to it is usually simple.  The sand-boxed guys, are well, sand-boxed; so it is exactly what it sonds, usually the SDK isolates you from the hardware and you don't really get the 'full embedded experience'.

Comment: Most small microcontrollers can at least handle a subset of C++ called "embedded C++", and most medium/large modern 32-bit microcontrollers like the ARM Cortex M3 series of cores, can easily handle C++.

Comment: @Warren My experience with micro- has been that they can't handle C++, maybe I've just been unlucky. ;-)  But yes, ARM Cortex X and the like can handle most anything you throw at it.

Answer (score 3):

Sure, for example, there are many operating systems in use in the embedded world. Working with embedded Linux is very different than working with a bare micro controller.

Answer (score 2):

"Learning embedded" sounds impossible to me. I do some work on headless linux computers controlling large machinery - which can be referred to as embedded (but it's not much different to programming any other computer, bar a few hardware interfaces). That's totally different to a phone, and totally different to an air conditioner or home automation system.

Control systems and mobile devices would be two categories of 'embedded' - but I'm sure there are plenty more.

Comment: `"Learning embedded" sounds impossible to me` That's exactly my point, I feel like "embedded" is everywhere. You almost need to specialize in something, or you won't be advancing much in any distinct area.

Comment: Learning c++ and c *is* doable :)

Comment: You don't learn "embedded", you learn a starter environment, and your tools.   You change environment (tools, CPU, board respin) and boom, you have to adjust, change, and learn a bit more stuff.

Answer (score 2):

I work on embedded linux on Mobile devices, and its whole lot different from a full flegded Ubuntu image where i write my code and cross compile it for the mobile device.

First of all a embedded system is stripped  down to meet the bare requirements of the device, very much unlike the traditional desktop operating system where you can have as many functionalities/libraries etc.

The memory constraints also are a major part of a embedded system. Hence all the programs/applications have to be written inorder to fit into the architecture. This **may not** be much of a concern on a traditional system.

Basically my point is to emphasize that working on embedded cannot be summed up into a few lines as each have a different purpose.

However programming keeping in view the overall architecture may help you gain confidence if you can fit into a project or not.

PS: I may not be good in categorizing which is what the question expects, however this is my bit on embedded systems.

Answer (score 2):

Lots of good answers already to this question.  I think you need to decide what the word embedded software means to you and/or what you want it to mean.  Maybe your definition isnt really embedded.  My definition means no operating system.  And that will probably upset many embedded software engineers, but the experienced ones like ones that have already answered will certainly understand our variations in definition and why.  I think they would call me a microcontroller specialist, and that is certainly true, but I spend most of my time on full speed processors with gobs of memory and rom and I/O, networking, etc.  I am the guy that brings the hardware up the first time, flushes out board and chip bugs, then hands it off to what most would call the embedded software engineers.  I am an electrical engineer by training and software engineer by trade, so I straddle the line.

It is very possible, and not uncommon that you could remain in the C/C++ embedded world, never have to read a datasheet or schematic, all you would do is call api's that someone else has created.  There is a large and increasingly larger market for that as what used to be (my definition of) true embedded, or rtos based embedded (which is often api calls and not the full experience) to this linux embedded thing that has exploded.  There is nothing wrong with it, it is fairly close to the experience of developing code for a desktop, but you have to try just a little harder for reliable code since it may be flash/rom based and they may not want to have weekly/monthly updates to units in the field.  Ideally never update, but that is also becoming more rare.

The rtos/embedded linux api based embedded is and can still be a different experience than what I call application programming.  You may still want or need to read a datasheet or schematic, you may still need to know assembler for the target platform.

I like all of the answers thus far to this question, I guess we are struggling to understand what you are really asking or what you are really looking for in life, add to that what we enjoy about our choices and you get this mix of answers.

I see a few groups, there is certainly the good old true embedded microcontroller stuff, but even that is turning into libraries and apis instead of on the metal, look at the arduino community and stellaris and a bunch of others.   I spend a lot of my time in board bring up and test, you have to know a fair amount about the whole system hardware, registers, schematic, etc.  Have to know enough assembler both to boot the thing out of reset as well as debug things by staring at disassembly dumps and looking for signs of life in the I/O or on memory busses, etc.  If lucky you will get to work on chip design as well and get to watch your instructions execute in simulation.  The next group is bootloader/operating system.  The hardware working well enough at this point, chip boots, memory appears to work, rom is there.  This team writes the production boot code and gets the product from power up into the embedded system, rtos, linux, vxworks, bsd, whatever.  this is a talent in and of itself, toolchain, root file system, etc.  The next group is the masses, the software engineers that write the applications for that operating system, now some will be reading datasheets, schematics, etc, writing device drivers or apis for others to use, and the highest level may be someone that is all application level programming, the api and sdk calls, some of which may be company developed some may be purchased or other.

Bottom line:  Absolutly, there are specialties within embedded.  Are you going to know everything?  NO, maybe 20 years ago, likely 40 years ago, not today the field is too big and wide.  What is the best things you can do for yourself in this field?  Learn assembler for a few different instruction sets.  The popular ones, arm definitely, thumb version of arm, maybe mips or powerpc or others.  If you lean toward microcontrollers, learn (arm, thumb,) avr, pic (blah), msp430, maybe 8051.  Read some data sheets, microcontrollers can teach you this even if that is not the field you want, tons of sub $50 development/eval boards (sparkfun.com for example) that give data sheets, simple schematics, assembler, C, etc.  If you are a software guy, learn to speak hardware guy, software and hardware folks do not speak the same language, if you can avoid picking sides and stay neutral and speak both languages you will help yourself, your career and whomever you work for and with.  Despite any personal views you may have about endians or bit or byte numbering, you are likely to have to deal with some screwy things, and speak to customers/coworkers that can only deal with octal (yeah really) or only deal with the msbit of anything being zero.  I recommend looking into verilog and maybe vhdl.  At least in a readable sense, not necessarily create it from scratch.  If you can already program and know C it is very readable.  Depending on the job and the coworkers the verilog and the schematic may be your only documentation you use to write your software.  If you cant do it they may replace you with someone who can (rather than get the hardware folks to document their stuff).

Comment: Oh, when someone wants me to write linux device driver, that is very high level to me and painful and can cause hesitation.  I prefer to punch through the operating system and write applications which are not operating system specific.  eventually you can develop your own solutions for writing one program that compiles embedded and application layer (with separate hal layers for each).